# Call method with implicit downcast

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a List defined as

```
List<ParentClass> parentClassList;
```

Parent class is abstract, so when I add elements to the List I do something like

```
parentClassList.add(new ChildClassOne(...));
parentClassList.add(new ChildClassTwo(...));
```

and so on... I actually have 5 child classes right now.

What I'd like to do is to call a method in another Class, overwriting its arguments, so:

```
public void doSomething(ChildClassOne arg) {...}
public void doSomething(ChildClassTwo arg) {...}
```

But if the type of the List is the parent Class I can't do

```
doSomething(parentClassList.get(0));
```

Basically I need to perform different actions based on the child's type and I need access to all the methods inside a specific child. Different childs have different methods, they have only one methods in common.

Comment: Instead of `doSomething(ChildClassOne arg)`, do `parentClass.doSomething()`, and override `doSomething()` in every subclass. That's the principle of polymorphism.

Comment: Basically generics are not covariant.  You can't change the type of a generic parameter.  You have to get `ParentClass` out if it because that's what you said was in it and you can't change that.

Comment: What did you mean by "overwriting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation a double dispatch technique called [*Visitor Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) becomes very handy:

```
interface Visitor {
    void visitChildOne(ChildOne child);
    void visitChildTwo(ChildTwo child);
    void visitChildThree(ChildThree child);
}

abstract class ParentClass {
    public abstract void accept(Visitor v);
    ...
}

class ChildClassOne extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) { v.visitChildOne(this); }
}
class ChildClassTwo extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) { v.visitChildTwo(this); }
}
class ChildClassThree extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) { v.visitChildThree(this); }
}
```

When you need to perform some task that does different things depending on the type of a child, provide an implementation of the `Visitor` interface, and pass it to `accept` of each of the children that you wish to process:

```
Visitor v = new Visitor() {
    @Override
    public void visitChildOne(ChildOne child) {
        System.out.println("Visiting child type 1");
        String someProperty = child.getPropertySpecificToChildOne();
    }
    @Override
    public void visitChildTwo(ChildTwo child) {
        System.out.println("Visiting child type 2");
        int someProperty = child.getPropertySpecificToChildTwo();
    }
    @Override
    public void visitChildThree(ChildThree child) {
        System.out.println("Visiting child type 3");
    }
};
for (Parent p: parentClassList) {
    p.accept(v);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will, like, works at all in the OPs example.  Could you show us how this works?

Comment: @markspace This patten was invented for doing things that OP wants to do. There is nothing in OP's situation that would prevent this pattern from working.

Comment: A nice variation of this pattern, if required, is to make the visitor generic (Visitor<T>), make all the visit() methods return T, and make the accept() method generic and return T, too.

Comment: @markspace I find it curious that you have immediately recognized this pattern in the other answer, where `doSomething` is overloaded, and did not think that it is going to work in my version, which removes overloading to make the pattern easier to understand by people without prior exposure to it.

Comment: @JBNizet That's certainly true - it makes it a lot easier to write code that transforms heterogeneous structures. I didn't want to overload OP with new info, though - that is why I picked a simplified version of the pattern implementation, which does not rely on overloading to complete the second leg of the double dispatch.

Comment: You got my upvote :-). I also find it easier to understand the pattern when overloading and generics are out of the picture. But for other readers, I thought this comment could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solved my problem and also helped me understanding the pattern

Answer (score 3):

Define an abstract emthod `doSomthing()` in `ParentClass`, and in each sub class you implement it like this:

```
class ChildClassOne {
    void doSomething() {
        instanceOfSomeOtherClass.doSomething(this); // will call the correct method
    }
}
```

and SomeOtherClass will have methods for each sub class:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    void doSomething(ChildClassOne o) {};
    void doSomething(ChildClassTwo o) {};
    void doSomething(ChildClassThree o) {};
    ...
}
```

You can read about this approach in regards to the [Visitor Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm)

**It might be even simpler if you moved the code from `SomeOtherClass` into the `ChildClass`es, though.**

Comment: This is basically the answer.  You should add that then in the `doSomething()` method change its argument type to `ParentClass`.

Comment: @markspace no, the nice part about this pattern is that there is a specfic method for each sub type in `SomeOtherClass`, so you do not have to do `instanceof`s

Comment: or the special behavior could be implemented right there in the Child classes `doSomething()`...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle :D just added that as a last advice this second myself.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I need to perform different actions based on the child's type and I need access to all the methods inside a specific child.

In this case the behavior you want to implement belongs into this specialized classes.

You might add another (abstract) method signature to the base class which you implement in the child classes providing the type depended behavior.

Comment: This is exactly how you end up with unimplemented methods in subclasses. You're suggesting an Animal class with a fly method.

Comment: @Sam *"You're suggesting an Animal class with a fly method"* - No. I suggest a class `Animal` with an abstract `move` method that is implemented as "fying" by some `Bird` sub classes.

Comment: He said he needs access to all the methods in Bird?

Comment: @Sam he said: *"Basically I need to perform different actions based on the child's type"*. That looks to me that this actions do really belong to the "child's type"... :o)